# All fonts on Chrome are very slightly duller (lighter & grayer) than on Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, fonts

This is such a subtle issue but it's driving me nuts!

Here's one example:
[image]

It's very subtle, but if you look closely you'll notice chrome's fonts are slightly duller / greyer and also a little bit different size.

Here's a closer look that more clearly shows how Firefox's font is darker:

[image]

Is this a problem that can be fixed? Or is it something different in browser rendering that cannot be changed? This happens with all fonts (system and web) on all websites.

Comment: Supposing you're on Windows, have you checked the status of ClearType in your Control Panel (just type "cleartype" in the search bar)? There's some fine-tuning to be done there to counter "crenelation" that some browsers can't handle too well with some web fonts. EDIT: you can also search "cleartype" directly from the Start menu.

Comment: Interesting! Oddly enough adjusting and enabling/disabling ClearType doesn't seem to affect Chrome's font display at all, while Firefox fonts (and as far as I can tell, all other things displaying fonts - music player, explorer, etc) do change in response.

Comment: Try to disable then re-enable hardware acceleration in your Chrome settings, then.

Answer (score 1):

You could try with this free extension: "Chrome font super enhancer" https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-font-super-enhance/ombebcdhklmmkcddekoplmobafpkolmd

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1136791)